# Cannot set the cookie DOMAIN in VueJS using VUE-COOKIES

Tags: javascript, cookies, vuejs2

- "vue": "^2.6.10"
- "vue-cookies": "^1.5.13"

I'm sending an HTTP POST request from the VueJS application using Axios to a backend server on a different machine. The value returned in the response is used to create a cookie like "exampleName":"exampleValue". So far so good.

> The problem is at the moment when I try to create the cookie with domain containing the address of the backend server.
>
> Without the correct domain value I get 401 status on all requests

During the tests, I changed the value of the domain **manually** in the devtools to the desired value (address of the backend server) and then the requisitions started to work (stopped receiving 401 status and started receiving 200 OK).

---

When using the function:

```
 api.post('http://...', form).then(response => {
      $cookies.set("keyExample", response.data);
 });
```

the cookie is **created** correctly, and I can see it in the Chrome devtools,

- But still **haven't the desired domain value:**

[image]

- **Desired:**

[image]

According to the documentation of the [**vue-cookies**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies) library, I could use something like:

```
$cookies.set (keyName, value [, expireTimes [, path [, domain [, secure]]])
```

to create the cookie already with the desired domain, but whenever I try this it fails, and the cookie is not even created.

I'm still trying:

```
// set domain
this.$cookies.set("key","value",null, null, "192.168.1.1"); // domain address
```

from the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies), but without success...

---

Am I thinking the right way?
Is there any other way to handle requests on different server?

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot create cookes for a domain that is not a parent of your own domain.  For instance, myplace.me.com could create a cookie for `myplace.me.com` or `me.com`, but not anything else.

Comment: I'm in the same LAN that this other machine, example:

My IP address: 192.168.1.10;
The backend server IP address: 192.168.1.15;

Even so I can not set the domain this way?

Comment: No.  The origin is dependent upon what is in the url.  Whatever is in your browser url as `[protocol]://[domain]:[port]`, **that** determines your origin, and what cookies look for

Comment: Now I have a better understanding of the _domains_.
Thank you very much, I'll try to deploy the application in the same machine that the backend api is hosted, maybe this will work.

Comment: the "backend" should be setting the cookie though ditch cookies and use localstorage if you're not specifically using the cookie for something like sessions, and if you are you shouldn't be setting it clientside anyway

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @Taplar:

> You **cannot** create cookies for a domain that is not a **parent** of your **own** domain. For instance, *myplace.me.com* could create a cookie for *myplace.me.com* or *me.com*, but not *anything* else.
>
> The origin is dependent upon what is in the URL. Whatever is in your browser URL as:

```
[protocol]://[domain]:[port]
http://  192.168.1.1 :8080
```

> that determines your origin, and what cookies look for.

---

- I'll try to deploy the VueJS application in the same machine that hosts the backend API, maybe this will work. Thanks.

---

- **UPDATE:** as explained by @Lawrence Cherone:

> The "backend" should be setting the cookie

I rewrote the backend code and it worked! Thank you very much!!!